# BASH - Summarising information present in 2 genotype data columns in one column (ped file)

Tags: python, ruby, perl, awk, bioinformatics

I have a PLINK ped file with 36 columns (6+30) that looks like this:

```
FID IID PID MID SEX PHENO SNP_1a SNP_1b SNP_2a SNP_2b SNP_3a SNP_3b SNP_4a SNP_4b SNP_5a SNP_5b SNP_6a SNP_6b SNP_7a SNP_7b SNP_8a SNP_8b SNP_9a SNP_9b SNP_10a SNP_10b SNP_11a SNP_11b SNP_12a SNP_12b SNP_13a SNP_13b SNP_14a SNP_14b SNP_15a SNP_15b
A1  A1  0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   2   2   1   2   1   2   1   2   2   1   2   1   1   1   1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   1   2   2
A2  A2  0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   2   2   2   2   2   1   1   0   0   2   1   2   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0
A3  A3  0   0   1   2   1   1   1   1   0   0   2   2   2   2   2   2   1   1   0   0   1   1   2   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0
```

I am interested in modifying the genotype columns (column 7 onwards) so that:

- If allele a **and/or** allele b for a SNP (SNP_#a and/or SNP_#b) is "**2**": summarise the 2 columns by a single column containing a "2"
- If **both** alleles (a and b) for a SNP are "**1**": summarise it with a "1" in the single column
- Finally, if **both** alleles (a and b) for a SNP are "**0**": summarise it with a "NA"

The output for the example above would thereby contain 21 columns (6+15) and look like this:

```
FID IID PID MID SEX PHENO SNP_1 SNP_2 SNP_3 SNP_4 SNP_5 SNP_6 SNP_7 SNP_8 SNP_9 SNP_10 SNP_11 SNP_11 SNP_12 SNP_13 SNP_14 SNP_15
A1  A1  0   0   1   1   NA  NA  2   2   2   2   2   2   1   2   NA  NA  NA  2   2
A2  A2  0   0   1   1   1   1   NA  2   2   2   1   NA  2   2   NA  NA  NA  1   NA
A3  A3  0   0   1   2   1   1   NA  2   2   2   1   NA  1   2   NA  NA  NA  1   NA
```

I hope someone can help me, thank you in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with bioinformatics terminology to interpret terms like 'SNP', to know which columns correspond to which alleles, or otherwise infer things about a PLINK file. Please clarify.

Comment: Come to think of it, I think you've overloaded the PLINK tag here. This PLINK tag applies to PuTTY-Link, not the plink genomics tool.

Comment: @kojiro: I corrected the tag, I though it was applying for the plink genomic tool as you have guessed it. I also added some more information (especially headers for the files) to make it more understandable. I hope it is more clear now. Thank you for your comments!

Comment: I think you would have more productivity with Python / Perl / Ruby / awk for projects like this.

Comment: @dawg: Thank you for this advice, I changed the tags.

Comment: Do we really need to see 36 columns summarized to 21? Can you reduce the **sample data** to 1--2 sample column sets that should be reduced, +1-2 columns that should have no processing and remain in output  (if appropriate)?  `awk` is designed for such data processing issues, and has a lower learning threshold (and setup) than other more fully featured languages. Good luck.

Comment: Do we REALLY need to see 36 columns for you to express your problem? Couldn't you express your problem in, say, 6 or 7 columns so it's a **Minimal** example for us to look at (see [ask] and [mcve])?

Comment: you're missing the case when for values are {0,1}.

Comment: @karakfa: this case does not exist

Comment: Well, it doesn't exist in this data. Are you saying it can never exist? I know next to nothing about bioinformatics.

Comment: @DaveCross: Exactly, in a PLINK bed file, either both alleles should be missing (i.e. 0) or neither.

Comment: I'm torn.  This is a fairly well stated question, nicely formatted.  On the other hand, it is a request for others to write your code for you.  I want to vote it up and down at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cat > test.awk
NR>1{
    for(i=j=7; i<NF; i+=2)                                              # for fields 7-(NF-1)
        $(j++) = ($i$(i+1)~/2/) ? "2" : (($i$(i+1)=="11") ? "1" : "NA") # see below *)
    for (i=1; i<=21; i++)                                               # reduced to 21 fields
        printf "%-2s%s", $i,(i<21?OFS:ORS)                              # print
} 
$ awk -f test.awk test.in
A1 A1 0  0  1  1  NA NA 2  2  2  2  2  2  1  2  NA NA NA 2  2
A2 A2 0  0  1  1  1  1  NA 2  2  2  1  NA 2  2  NA NA NA 1  NA
A3 A3 0  0  1  2  1  1  NA 2  2  2  1  NA 1  2  NA NA NA 1  NA
```

If rules 1 (2 OR 2) or 2 (1 AND 1) fail, it returns `NA`.

*) Catenate a and b fields (`$i$(i+1)`, add 2 to `i` on every iteration) and check them for 2 or 11 and write result to already processed cols (ie. result from fields 7 & 8 is stored to field 7, 9 & 10 to 8 etc. grow `j` by 1 on every iteration).

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

here is another cryptic `awk` with  headers

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<7;i++) printf "%s ",$i; 
        for(i=7;i<=NF;i+=2) 
           {c=$i^2+$(i+1)^2; 
            r=(c>1)+(c>3); 
            printf "%2s ",(NR>1)?(r?r:"NA"):substr($i,1,length($i)-1)}; 
            print ""}' file

FID IID PID MID SEX PHENO SNP_1 SNP_2 SNP_3 SNP_4 SNP_5 SNP_6 SNP_7 SNP_8 SNP_9 SNP_10 SNP_11 SNP_12 SNP_13 SNP_14 SNP_15
A1 A1 0 0 1 1 NA NA  2  2  2  2  2  2  1  2 NA NA NA  2  2
A2 A2 0 0 1 1  1  1 NA  2  2  2  1 NA  2  2 NA NA NA  1 NA
A3 A3 0 0 1 2  1  1 NA  2  2  2  1 NA  1  2 NA NA NA  1 NA
```

Comment: Love it. I had the headers too with `gensub` in my ternary operator chain but it got too long and didn't fit on the screen so I ditched it.

Answer (score 2):

What have you tried? We're not here to write your code for you.

But as I'm feeling generous, here's a pretty basic Perl solution that seems to work for your data. I'm not going to explain it as I think you should put in some effort :-)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

# Skip header
<DATA>;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my @data = split;
  my @fixed = @data[0..5];
  my @snps = @data[6..$#data];
  my @new_snps;
  while (my ($s1, $s2) = splice @snps,0, 2) {
    push @new_snps, summarise($s1, $s2);
  }
  say join ' ', @fixed, @new_snps;
}

sub summarise {
  my ($s1, $s2) = @_;

  return 2 if $s1 == 2 or $s2 == 2;
  return 1 if $s1 == 1 and $s2 == 1;
  return 'NA' if $s1 == 0 and $s2 == 0;
  return '?';
}

__DATA__
FID IID PID MID SEX PHENO SNP_1a SNP_1b SNP_2a SNP_2b SNP_3a SNP_3b SNP_4a SNP_4b SNP_5a SNP_5b SNP_6a SNP_6b SNP_7a SNP_7b SNP_8a SNP_8b SNP_9a SNP_9b SNP_10a SNP_10b SNP_11a SNP_11b SNP_12a SNP_12b SNP_13a SNP_13b SNP_14a SNP_14b SNP_15a SNP_15b
A1  A1  0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   2   2   1   2   1   2   1   2   2   1   2   1   1   1   1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   1   2   2
A2  A2  0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   2   2   2   2   2   1   1   0   0   2   1   2   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0
A3  A3  0   0   1   2   1   1   1   1   0   0   2   2   2   2   2   2   1   1   0   0   1   1   2   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0
```